# Nexus Maven Central URL for downloading artifacts

Tags: url, maven, nexus

I'm using nexus 1.9.0.1 and I'm trying to point to maven central. We have a firewall. I have access to 207.223.240.88 and 207.223.240.89. What is the correct url/address to put into the nexus "maven central" repo to be able to download artifacts without being treated as a "scraper" ? This used to work but although those two IPs are open nexus can't find the artifacts.

thanks,
fred

Answer (score 3):

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2

Nexus comes with this configured out of the box. You won't be treated as a scraper unless you are in fact scraping the repo. We can tell the difference.